# Find two closest points in 2D distribution

Tags: algorithm, geometry, kdtree

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the two closest points in a list of 2D points (each point has an x and y attribute).

One approach that's better than brute force would be to sort of quantize out the space into overlapping blocks (along the lines of a 2D convolution) and brute force the distance calculations within each block.

That said, I thought maybe someone who knows more about kd-trees or high dimension indices like the sort generated to create approximate nearest neighbors lookup trees could be better solutions to this problem, so I wanted to ask:

Are there intelligent / known algorithms for effectively computing the closest two points in a (2D) distribution? Any suggestions others can offer on this front would be hugely helpful!

Comment: To me it looks like a job for path finding algs.

Comment: If you want to find shortest path between multiple points (3 or more) I don't think there's a very fast algorithm for this, I believe you are talking about [Traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm) ?

Comment: Thanks! Is there any smarter approaches that run in linear time? I feel with quantization there could be a very fast technique indeed

Comment: IMHO this would only work if your data is not skewed and you could somehow guess an adequate box size. Building a hierarchical index structure first would solve these problems for you but will also cost O(N log N)

Answer (score 1):

The classical Divide & Conquer approach works in time O(n log(n)). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Have a closer look at the Note 3, and look for Rabin's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

It's well known problem in competitive programming.
Here's my implementation for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#define x first
#define y second
#define INF 100000000

using namespace std;

int n;

typedef pair<int, int> point;

point tab1[100000];
point tab2[100000];

long long distance(point a, point b){
    return abs(a.x - b.x) + abs(a.y - b.y);
}

long long closestpair(int p, int k){
    if(p == k){
        return INF;
    }
    if(k - p == 1){
        return distance(tab1[p], tab1[k]);
    }
    int mid = (p + k) / 2;
    int count = 1;
    long long dl = closestpair(p, mid - 1);
    long long dp = closestpair(mid, k);
    long long len = min(dl, dp);

    for(int i = p; i <= k; i++){
        if(abs(tab1[i].x - tab1[mid].x) <= len){
            tab2[count] = make_pair(-tab1[i].y, tab1[i].x);
            count++;
        }
    }
    sort(tab2 + 1, tab2 + count + 1);
    for(int i = 1; i < count; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < min(7, count - 1); j++){
            len = min(len, distance(tab2[i], tab2[j]));
        }
    }
    return len;
}

int main(){
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++){
        cin >> tab1[i].x >> tab1[i].y;
    }
    sort(tab1 + 1, tab1 + n + 1);
    cout << closestpair(1, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I found some explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/)