# Find Nearest Point Pair (Divide & Conquer), Issue when have many of same x coordinates

Tags: java, nearest-neighbor, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to develop the Divide & Conquer algorithm for finding the closest 2 points in an array of points.

I'm finding that when the input has a few points with the same x coordinates. Then if 2 of them are divided between Section1 and Section2 I get incorrect results. I'm showing here a minimal input just  to show the problem. (As well as a larger input to show that the problem stays with larger input as well). My concern is for when I have many points with the same x coordinates.

I thought about a solution. If I extend the Point2D class and add a field to store the points index in the `pointsSortedOnX` array, then I can create the `pointsSortedOnY` array from this class. Now when I go thru the `pointsSortedOnY` array instead of checking if the point is equal or less then `midX` I can check if it's less or equal to the `mid` index of `pointsSortedOnX`.
I'm just wondering if there isn't a better way.

Input (minimal):

```
double[][] p = {
        {25.6, 67.9},
        {25.6, 8.65},
        {32.35, 81.26},
        {25.32, 67.15},
}
```

Input (To show problem is in larger input as well):

```
double[][] p = {
        {25.6, 67.9},
        {25.6, 8.65},
        {32.35, 81.26},
        {25.32, 67.15},

        {25.6, 60.95},
        {25.6, 56.79},
        {25.6, 78.49},
        {25.6, 6.23},
        {25.6, 7.9},
        {25.6, 95.9},
        {25.6, 35.9},
        {25.6, 10.9},
    }
```

Code:

```
    /** Return the distance of the closest PointPair of points */
public static PointPair getClosestPair(double[][] points) {
    int size = points.length;
    pointsSortedX = new Point2D.Double[size];
    pointsSortedY = new Point2D.Double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pointsSortedX[i] = new Point2D.Double(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
        pointsSortedY[i] = new Point2D.Double(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
    
    }
    Arrays.sort(pointsSortedX, (e1, e2) -> 
        (e1.getX() == e2.getX() ? (e1.getY() > e2.getY() ? 1 : (e1.getY() < e2.getY() ? -1 : 0)) : (e1.getX() > e2.getX() ? 1 : -1)));
    Arrays.sort(pointsSortedY, (e1, e2) -> 
        (e1.getY() > e2.getY() ? 1 : (e1.getY() < e2.getY() ? -1 : 0)));
        
    return findNearstPair(pointsSortedX, 0, size - 1, pointsSortedY, 1);
}

    /** Return the distance of the closest PointPair of points
 * in pointsOrderedOnX[low..high]. This is a recursive
 * method. pointsOrderedOnX and pointsOrderedOnY are
 * not changed in the subsequent recursive calls.
*/
public static PointPair findNearstPair(Point2D[] pointsOrderedOnX, int low, int high, Point2D[] pointsOrderedOnY) {
    if (low == high)
        return new PointPair(pointsOrderedOnX[low], pointsOrderedOnX[high], Double.MAX_VALUE);
    else if ((high - low) == 1)
        return new PointPair(pointsOrderedOnX[low], pointsOrderedOnX[high], pointsOrderedOnX[low].distance(pointsOrderedOnX[high]));
    else{
        // Divide
        int mid = (high - low) / 2;

        PointPair leftPair = findNearstPair(pointsOrderedOnX, low, low + mid, pointsOrderedOnY);
        PointPair rightPair = findNearstPair(pointsOrderedOnX, low + mid + 1, high, pointsOrderedOnY);
        
        // Merge the right & left
        shortestPair = leftPair.distance > rightPair.distance ? rightPair : leftPair;
        System.out.println("shortest "  + shortestPair);
        
        // Find points in pointsOrderedOnY that belong in stripL & stripR
        // this any x that is less then d away from the middle of
        // the 2 sections (between mid & mid + 1)
        double minXinS1 = pointsOrderedOnX[low].getX();
        // <= midX is S1(left side) > midX is S2(right side)
        double midX = pointsOrderedOnX[low + mid].getX();
        double maxXinS2 = pointsOrderedOnX[high].getX();

        List<Integer> stripL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> stripR = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int p = 0; p < pointsOrderedOnY.length; p++){
            double pX = pointsOrderedOnY[p].getX();
            
            double pY =pointsOrderedOnY[p].getY();
            
            // is in S1 & less then distance away from middle
            // >= minXinS1 & <= midX & >= midX - d = stripL
            if(pX <= midX && pX >= minXinS1 && pX >= midX - shortestPair.distance){
                stripL.add(p);
            }
            //is in S2 & less then distance away from middle
            // > midX && <= maxXinS2 & > midX & < midX + d
            else if(pX > midX && pX <= maxXinS2 && pX < midX + shortestPair.distance){
                stripR.add(p);
            }
        }
        
        // For each point in stripL find the points in stripR that are less then
        // distance away (max 6 points in stripR)
        int stripRIndx = 0; // 
        for(int p = 0; p < stripL.size(); p++){
            double pY = pointsOrderedOnY[stripL.get(p)].getY();
            
            // Skip points in stripR that are below pY - distance
            while(stripRIndx < stripR.size() && pointsOrderedOnY[stripR.get(stripRIndx)].getY() 
                            <= pY - shortestPair.distance)
                stripRIndx++;
                
            // Check points in stripR that ate within pY +/- distance
            int tempStripRIndex = stripRIndx;
            while(tempStripRIndex < stripR.size() && pointsOrderedOnY[stripR.get(tempStripRIndex)].getY()
                            <= pY + shortestPair.distance){
                if(pointsOrderedOnY[stripL.get(p)].distance(pointsOrderedOnY[stripR.get(tempStripRIndex)]) < shortestPair.distance){
                    shortestPair.p1 = pointsOrderedOnY[stripL.get(p)];
                    shortestPair.p2 = pointsOrderedOnY[stripR.get(tempStripRIndex)];
                    shortestPair.distance = pointsOrderedOnY[stripL.get(p)].distance(pointsOrderedOnY[stripR.get(tempStripRIndex)]);
                }
                tempStripRIndex++;
            }
        }
        return shortestPair;
    }
}

class PointPair {
Point2D p1;
Point2D p2;
double distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

PointPair(){}

PointPair(Point2D p1, Point2D p2, double distance) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    this.distance = distance;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return p1 + ":" + p2 + " distance = " + distance;
}
```

**EDIT**
I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736485/find-two-closest-points-in-2d-distribution). I'm looking to find what is **wrong** in **my code** and how to fix it. I'm trying to implement the same idea as is mentioned there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find two closest points in 2D distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736485/find-two-closest-points-in-2d-distribution)

Comment: @Progman The first answer is in C++ I'm not familiar with. The second answer refers to Wikipedia. I now about the divide and conquer as mentioned in my question. My issue was in  he implementation. If you have a chance let me know if the way I implemented it in my answer is correct. It doesn't seem to be quicker then the brute force implementation.

Answer (score 0):

After further analysing my code, this is what I came up with.

Code:

```
    public static PointPair findNearstPair(Point2D[] pointsOrderedOnX, int low, int high, Point2D[] pointsOrderedOnY) {
    PointPair shortestPair;

    if (low == high)
        return new PointPair(pointsOrderedOnX[low], pointsOrderedOnX[high], Double.MAX_VALUE);
    else if ((high - low) == 1)
        return new PointPair(pointsOrderedOnX[low], pointsOrderedOnX[high], pointsOrderedOnX[low].distance(pointsOrderedOnX[high]));

    // Divide
    int mid = (high - low) / 2;
    PointPair leftPair = findNearstPair(pointsOrderedOnX, low, low + mid, pointsOrderedOnY);
    PointPair rightPair = findNearstPair(pointsOrderedOnX, low + mid + 1, high, pointsOrderedOnY);

    // Merge the right & left
    shortestPair = leftPair.distance > rightPair.distance ? rightPair : leftPair;

    /* Find points in pointsOrderedOnY that belong in stripL & stripR
      * this any x that is less then d away from the middle of
      * the 2 sections (between mid & mid + 1)
      */
    double midX = pointsOrderedOnX[low + mid].getX();
    double midY = pointsOrderedOnX[low + mid].getY();

    double leftS1 = pointsOrderedOnX[low].getX();
    double leftStripL = Math.max(leftS1, midX - shortestPair.distance);
    double rightS2 = pointsOrderedOnX[high].getX();
    double rightStripR = Math.min(rightS2, midX + shortestPair.distance);

    List<Integer> stripL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> stripR = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int p = 0; p < pointsOrderedOnY.length; p++) {
        double pX = pointsOrderedOnY[p].getX();
        double pY = pointsOrderedOnY[p].getY();

        if (pX >= leftStripL && pX <= rightStripR) { // in current section(S1 & S2)
            if (pX == midX) {
                if (pointsOrderedOnX[mid + low] == pointsOrderedOnY[p]) {
                    stripL.add(p);
                } else if (pY == midY) {
                    shortestPair.p1 = pointsOrderedOnX[mid + low];
                    shortestPair.p2 = pointsOrderedOnY[p];
                    shortestPair.distance = shortestPair.p1.distance(shortestPair.p2);
                    return shortestPair;
                } else if (pY > midY) {
                    stripR.add(p);
                } else {
                    stripL.add(p);
                }
            } else if (pX > midX) {
                stripR.add(p);
            } else {
                stripL.add(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works even when the input has many items that divide between S1 & S2.

The main difference in this code is that when I find a point that the x coordinate is the same as the x coordinate of `mid` I check the y coordinate. if its less then the y coordinate of `mid` then it goes into `stripL`. If it's greater it goes into `stripR`. If it is equal then I check if it's the same point as `mid` then it's in `stripL` if not it means we have 2 points with the same coordinates, this will be the closest 2 points, so I return the pair.